# What does 到达境外经转局 mean?

Tags: translation

I’m expecting a package from China and tracking shows the last comment as 到达境外经转局

Any help with this translation?

Comment: There are ways you can get yourself started on translations: e.g. [Google Translate](https://translate.google.cn/#view=home&op=translate&sl=zh-CN&tl=en&text=%E5%88%B0%E8%BE%BE%E5%A2%83%E5%A4%96%E7%BB%8F%E8%BD%AC%E5%B1%80) gives *Arrival at the Overseas Economic Transfer Bureau*, and there's [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E5%88%B0%E8%BE%BE%E5%A2%83%E5%A4%96%E7%BB%8F%E8%BD%AC%E5%B1%80) for a word-by-word translation.  I think all Stack Exchange sites require some prior effort shown, i.e., an answer to *what have you tried and why didn't it work?*.

Answer (score 1):

到达 = arrive

境外 = abroad

经转局 =  processing/ transit center

到达境外经转局 = Arrived at processing center abroad (The package is currently in a  processing center in your country awaiting transit )